# JAAS DIGEST аутентификация. Как извлечь чистый хеш пароля?

Tags: java

Ниже кусок кода моего LoginModule:

```
public boolean login() throws LoginException {
    Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
    callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("login");
    callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password", false);
    try {
        this.handler.handle(callbacks);
        String name=((NameCallback)(callbacks[0])).getName();
        String password= String.valueOf(((PasswordCallback)callbacks[1]).getPassword());
System.out.println(password);
         MessageDigest md=null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         md.update(new String("user123").getBytes("UTF-8")); 
         if (name != null &&
              name.equals("user123") &&
              password != null &&
              MessageDigest.isEqual(password.getBytes(),md.digest())) {
                login = name;
                userGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
                userGroups.add("admin");
                return true;
            }
       // If credentials are NOT OK we throw a LoginException
          throw new LoginException("Authentication failed");
    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    return false;
}
```

Насколько я понял getPassword возвращает response=MD5(HA1:nonce:HA2). А как правильно сравнивать хеши паролей. К примеру если в базе лежит хеш только пароля?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ - никак. Следует хранить в базе хеш login:realm:password. А механизм сравнения примерно такой:

```
public boolean login() throws LoginException {
    Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[8];
    callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("login");
    callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password", false);
    callbacks[2]= new TextInputCallback("cnonce");
    callbacks[3]= new TextInputCallback("md5a2");
    callbacks[4]= new TextInputCallback("nc");
    callbacks[5]= new TextInputCallback("nonce");
    callbacks[6]= new TextInputCallback("qop");
    callbacks[7]= new TextInputCallback("realmName");

    try {
        this.handler.handle(callbacks);
        String name=((NameCallback)(callbacks[0])).getName();
        String password= String.valueOf(((PasswordCallback)callbacks[1]).getPassword());
        String cnonce= String.valueOf(((TextInputCallback)callbacks[2]).getText());
        String md5a2= String.valueOf(((TextInputCallback)callbacks[3]).getText());
        String nc= String.valueOf(((TextInputCallback)callbacks[4]).getText());
        String nonce= String.valueOf(((TextInputCallback)callbacks[5]).getText());
        String qop= String.valueOf(((TextInputCallback)callbacks[6]).getText());
        String realmName= String.valueOf(((TextInputCallback)callbacks[7]).getText());


        // Here we validate the credentials against some
          // authentication/authorization provider.
          // It can be a Database, an external LDAP, 
          // a Web Service, etc.
          // For this tutorial we are just checking if 
          // user is "user123" and password is "pass123"
        /*System.out.println(password);
          if (name != null &&
              name.equals("user123") &&
              password != null &&
              password.equals("pass123")) {*/ 
        System.out.println(password);
        MessageDigest ha1=null;
        MessageDigest response=null;
        try {
            ha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            response = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String dbpassword="user123";
        ha1.update(new String(name+":"+realmName+":"+dbpassword).getBytes()); //здесь нужно брать ha1 прямо из базы.
        String ha2=md5a2;
        response.update(new String(byteArrayToHex(ha1.digest())+":"+nonce+":"+nc+":"+cnonce+":"+qop+":"+ha2).getBytes());

        byte[] bts=response.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bts) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }
        System.out.println("digested(hex):" + sb.toString());
        if(qop.equals("auth")){
            response.update(new String().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } 

          if (name != null &&
              name.equals("user123") &&
              password != null &&
              MessageDigest.isEqual(password.getBytes(),ha1.digest())) {
                // We store the username and roles
                // fetched from the credentials provider
                // to be used later in commit() method.
                // For this tutorial we hard coded the
                // "admin" role
                login = name;
                userGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
                userGroups.add("admin");
                return true;
            }
       // If credentials are NOT OK we throw a LoginException
          throw new LoginException("Authentication failed");
    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```